# Remove duplicate rows in mysqldb in a specific way

Tags: python, mysql, duplicates, mysql-python

I want to delete the duplicate rows in my mysqldb table, where 4 columns value is the same. How can i do it if I have got an auto_increment column too?

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE test
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

How can i implement this part of code to do this in Python?

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
            user='admin',
            passwd='',
            db='database1',
            use_unicode=True,
            charset="utf8")
 cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your auto increment column is named  id 
You could use a not in clause

```
  delete from  my_table 
  where id not IN (
   select max(id)
   from  my_table 
   group by col1, col2, col3, col4
   )
```

id this way you delete all the row that have more then on istance for the same col1, col2, col3, col4 and you let in db the row with max(id) for each of this

Comment: What about if I have a second column what is show the upload time? Upload time is always differente too, how can i implement it in this way? + if i need the older data, i have to use min(id) ? Am i right?

Comment: for the older data you can use min(..)  for the second column .....  i don't undertsand your comment...  explain better or show proper data sample and  the exact expected  result